# C++ Restricting variable type to multiple base classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, types

Consider the following classes:

```
class A {};
class B {};
class C {};

class D : public A, public B, public C {};
class E : public A, public C {};
class F : public A {};
```

I want to write a variable type that only accepts types which derive from both `A` and `B` (in this case only `D`) so that the following hold:

```
T var;
var = D(); // valid
var = E(); // invalid, does not derive from B
var = F(); // invalid, does not derive from B
```

I could do the following and use `G` as my type. `G` would act as a sort of 'type grouper'.

```
class G : public A, public B {};

class D : public F, public C {};
```

However if I want to apply this to any combination of base types or with any number of base types, I would need a large number of these type groupers. Is there a way to implement a multiple base type requirement without manually generating type groupers like I showed?

I do not have a specific use case that requires this, I am purely curious whether this is possible.

EDIT: Accidentally used `F` twice. Switched to `G` for the second time.

Comment: What do you mean by "variable type that only accepts types"? Is this hypothetical `T` holding a copy of both `A,B`? Are you using `var` in some template context and require `A,B` functionality? I think this is XY problem, please show how you want to use `var` given some magical `T` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Here is a type that *references* (points to) an object that derives from both `A` and `B`. The simplest barebones version is

```
struct AB
{
  A* a;
  B* b;
  template <class D> AB(D* d) : a(d), b(d) {};
  template <class D> AB& operator=(D* d) { a=d; b=d; return *this;}
};
```

Now you can have:

```
D d;
E e;
AB ab1(&d); // OK
AB ab2(&e); // Not OK
```

This can be templatized and expanded:

```
template <typename ... As>
struct Combine
{
   std::tuple<As * ...> as;
   template <class D> As(D* d) : as(replicate<sizeof...(As)>(d) {};
   // etc etc --- writing `replicate` is left ans an exercise
};
```

One could add data hiding, accessors, static asserts, concepts, smart pointers and whatnot on top of this, but the idea is still the same. If you derive from A and B, you have an A part and a B part. Let me reference both.

Providing a pair of pointers/references to `A` and to `B` is the only reasonable interface one could expect from such a type (without knowing specific details about A and B).

Ostensibly one can also have a type that copies, rather than references.

```
struct CopyingAB : A, B
{
  template <class D> CopyingAB(const D& d) : A(d), B(d) {};
  template <class D> CopyingAB& operator=(const D& d) 
    { 
      A::operator=(d); 
      B::operator=(d); 
      return *this;
    }
};
```

*But you should never want or need this, because object slicing is a bug, not a feature*.

There are probably no real use cases for the referencing/pointing version either, but it is not inherently evil in and of itself, so let it be.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357485/13805358), but using [constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) in C++20.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};

class D : public A, public B, public C {};
class E : public A, public C {};
class F : public A {};

template<class T>
concept AB = std::derived_from<T, A> && std::derived_from<T, B>;

template<AB T>
T *newAB() {
    return new T;
}

int main() {
    auto d = newAB<D>();
    auto e = newAB<E>(); // error: 'E' does not satisfy 'AB'
    auto f = newAB<F>(); // error: 'F' does not satisfy 'AB'
}
```

Comment: `newAB<D>()` does exactly the same thing as `new D`, and `d` has type `D*`. There is no *variable type* that only accepts types which derive from both A and B anywhere. There is a *function template* that accepts template parameters which derive from both A and B, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: idea can be extended to a erasure-type with constructor using that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If using C++11 can do this. Later versions offer some tweaks.

The closest I think you can get is using is_base_of and static_asserts, or a function which checks both with static_assert.
e.g.

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
  
template <class T>
void CheckClassesAreDerivedFromAandB()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "Check we are derived from A");
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, T>::value, "Check we are derived from B");
}

template <class T>
void CheckClassesAreDerivedFromAandB(const T&)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "Check we are derived from A");
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, T>::value, "Check we are derived from B");
}

class D : public A, public B, public C {};
class E : public A, public C {};
class F : public A {}; 

void test()
{
    CheckClassesAreDerivedFromAandB<D>();
    
    D d;
    CheckClassesAreDerivedFromAandB(d);
}
```

You could even combine this into a factory method.

```
template <class T>
T* Create()
{
    CheckBaseClassesAreDerivedFromAandB<T>();
    return new T();
}

template <class T>
T Build()
{
    CheckBaseClassesAreDerivedFromAandB<T>();
    return T();
}
void test()
{
    auto d = Create<D>();
    auto e = Create<E>(); // compile error here
    auto another_d = Build<D>();
    ...
}
```